# Easiest way to calculate Runge-Kutta stability function

Tags: numerical-methods

For a Runge–Kutta method with Runge–Kutta matrix $A$ and weights $b_1, \ldots, b_s$ the stability function is defined as:
$$R(\zeta) = 1 + \zeta \begin{pmatrix} b_1, \ldots, b_s \end{pmatrix}(I-\zeta A)^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \, .$$

What is the easiest way to determine $R(\zeta)$?

The inverse of the matrix makes it quite complicated.

Comment: I don't know much about this topic, but see page 9 of http://www.win.tue.nl/casa/meetings/seminar/previous/_abstract020220_files/talk.pdf.

Comment: Applying Cramer's rule yields
$$
R(\zeta) = \frac{\operatorname{det}(I - \zeta A + \zeta \mathbb 1 b^\top)}{\operatorname{det}(I - \zeta A)}
$$

Comment: The proof can be found here (click "Look inside", it's on the first two pages) http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-05221-7_3

Comment: The formula given by @uranix simplifies for explicit methods to just the nominator, i.e., the denominator is 1.